# install IIS from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, iis, x86, x86-64, windows-server-2016

Всем привет. Пытаюсь запустить IIS на WinServ16 с помощью команды:

```
Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools
```

Эта команда помещена в скрипт, который добавлен в блок "provisioners" файла packerFile.json.
Общая структура такова. ОС хоста-Вин10, Гостевой машины ВинСервер16. Доп программы: packer, vagrant, virtualBox.

Процесс установки сервера в гостевой системе обрывается ошибкой:

> install-windowsfeature is not recognized an internal or external command.....

Как я прочитал это свидельствует о том, что запускаемый участок кода предназначен для х64 архитектуры, а запускается в PSx32, который не поддерживает этот модуль (имеется в виду Server Manager). Но при этом разрядность гостевой системы х64 и по умолчанию должен запускаться PSx64 как я полагаю. Если например запустить PS из:
`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` и ввести в нем **[environment]::Is64BitProcess** результатом будет **true**.

В свою очередь из папки 
`C:\Windows\SysWow64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` **[environment]::Is64BitProcess** выдаст **false**, и такую же ошибку при выполнении команды 
`Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools` как и при выполнении скрипта через packer.

При попытке добавить в скрипт логический блок:

```
if([Environment]::Is64BitProcess)
{   
    Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-Server -IncludeManagementTools;
}else{
    Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"
    //это директория с х64 версией
}
```

И запустить его в PSx32 открывается новое окно PS(типа х64), но проверка `([environment]::Is64BitProcess)` снова выдает "false", при том, что прямой запуск файла из  директории System32 и выполнение этой проверки выдают "true"

Как в данном случае запустить IIS?

Вся сборка скачана по этой ссылке, образ системы тот же, что и в линке:
[github.com-joefitzgerald-packer-windows](https://github.com/joefitzgerald/packer-windows)

Answer (score 0):

32х-битные программы видят вместо папки System32 папку SysWow64, это фича такая.

Чтобы обратиться к 64х-битной папке System32 из 32х-битной программы, нужно использовать псевдоним SysNative

Comment: это не совсем программа, это просто скрипт.... не думаю, что у него есть различия х32 или х64. Или вы имеете в виду изменить блок: }else{ на 
   `Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"` ??

Comment: @AndreyRudoy ваш "просто скрипт" исполняется программой powershell

Comment: Да, безусловно. Но почему при х64 системе у меня для выполнения скриптов грузится PSx32? Это тоже фича такая? изменение команды на ту которая с псевдонимом не решило проблему, итогом сборки packer была ошибка `The system cannot find file C:\windows\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\x1.0\powershell.exe`

Comment: @AndreyRudoy а запускает-то ваши скрипты кто?

Comment: 64х битный powershell хост машины. Но вопрос все равно остается актуальным. Из 3х попыток сбилдить бокс, все 3 завершились ошибками. Для первой попытки скрипту, точнее компилятору не понравилась конструкция if(ошибка увы уже затерлась логированием ps) во втором случае, то же самое, что и в третьем, "файл не найден", за исключением только разницы в написании $env:WinDir.... против С:\windows

Comment: @AndreyRudoy вот, у вас уже какой-то хост появился... Продолжайте рассказывать, может в какойто момент и станет понятно что произошло

Comment: ок. Дополнил вопрос информацией. Это все происходит на виртуальной машине. packer разворачивает исходный образ, устанавливает необходимые компоненты, и впоследствии заворачивает в бокс, который уже поднимается в последствии на виртуальной машине. Сейчас сложность заключается именно в установке iis, и судя по всему вследствие того, что открывается 32х разрядная версия ПС